# In eclipse, how to I set up a project with maven-style src/main and src/test without it showing a src folder underneath in the package explorer?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I want to create a java project with src/main and src/test for the main and test classes. When I create two source folders src/main and src/test, I end up with this in the package explorer:

[image]

But I don't want the 'src' folder to be displayed there. Is there any way to achieve this? I want something like (mock up):

[image]

Or possibly (mock up):

[image]

Comment: In Maven you should use `src/main/java` for production code and `src/test/java` for the unit tests. If you have resources you should use `src/main/resources` for the resources which should end up in the resulting jar file and for resources which are only needed during unit tests you should put them into `src/test/resources`....furthermore create a pom file and reimport that project into Eclipse via M2E...

Comment: Since the shown ´src/main/´ is more or less a link to ´src´ (and it's subfolder) there's no real way to remove that folder. However, you could try to filter it from your project view i guess (no eclipse at hand atm)

Comment: @khmarbaise What you wrote is true, but how is it related in any way to the OP's question?

Comment: @khmarbaise and skomisa Yes, I forgot about the final "java" folder, but it doesn't affect the intention of the question.